# How to refer to individual elements in the file?

Tags: json, vue.js

Good afternoon, tell me please, I created the calendar, but now I want the calendar to show all the events that I have recorded in a separate file JSON. I get information from the file JSON. Now I try to do the following: get all the 'start_at' items in item 'events' and compare them with all dates on the calendar and where they are true add the description from the list that has the memo designation on that day on the calendar.

Help me: make a correct comparison of the dates of the start_at and dates in the calendar, because now I have such an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPY20.png)

My JSON file:

```
    {
  "meta": {
    "unremovable": [
      1
    ],
    "types": [
      [
        1,
        "public_holiday"
      ],
      [
        2,
        "day_off"
      ],
      [
        4,
        "birthday"
      ],
      [
        8,
        "meeting"
      ],
      [
        16,
        "other"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 211,
      "starts_at": "2019-03-08",
      "ends_at": "2019-03-08",
      "memo": "Международный женский день",
      "type": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 212,
      "starts_at": "2019-10-07",
      "ends_at": "2019-10-07",
      "memo": "День учителя",
      "type": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 213,
      "starts_at": "2019-10-14",
      "ends_at": "2019-10-14",
      "memo": "День защитника Украины",
      "type": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 214,
      "starts_at": "2019-10-18T14:00:00Z",
      "ends_at": "2019-10-18T15:00:00Z",
      "memo": "Созвон с Киевом",
      "type": 8
    },
    {
      "id": 215,
      "starts_at": "2019-10-18T09:00:00Z",
      "ends_at": "2019-10-18T13:15:00Z",
      "memo": "Велопрогулка",
      "type": 16
    },
    {
      "id": 216,
      "starts_at": "2019-10-22",
      "ends_at": "2019-10-22",
      "memo": "Гуляем в парке",
      "type": 16
    },
    {
      "id": 217,
      "starts_at": "2019-10-28",
      "ends_at": "2019-11-03",
      "memo": "Конференция",
      "type": 18
    }, 
    {
      "id": 218,
      "starts_at": "2019-11-03T21:43:00Z",
      "ends_at": "2019-11-03T21:43:00Z",
      "memo": "Самолёт домой",
      "type": 16
    },
    {
      "id": 219,
      "starts_at": "2019-11-11",
      "ends_at": "2019-11-11",
      "memo": "ДР",
      "type": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

My code:

```
<template>
  <div class="all">
    <div class="overflow-div">
      <div class="pagination">
        <div @click="prevPage" class="btn-left"><</div> 
        <p>{{ nameOfOneMonth }} {{ year }}</p>
        <div @click="nextPage" class="btn-right">></div> 
      </div>

        <div class="d_nameOfDays">
          <li v-for="day in nameOfDays" class="nameOfDays">{{ day }}</li>
        </div>
        <transition :name="nameOfClass" >
          <div :key="currentPage" class="fade_wrapper">
            <div v-for="(week, i) in getCalendar" class="d_day">
            <li v-for="day in week" class="li_day">
            <div class="day" 
               v-bind:class="{ 'grey': isAnotherMonth(i, day), 'currentDay': currentDayOnCalendar(day) }"
               >{{ day }}</div>
            </li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </transition>
    </div>
  </div> 
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      currentPage: 0,
      namesOfMonths: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      nameOfOneMonth: '',
      nameOfDays: ['Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс'],
      date: new Date(),
      isActive: true,
      year: '',
      nameOfClass: '',
      eventsData: []
    }
  },
  created: function(){
    fetch('src/Calendar_data.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => (
      this.eventsData = data
      ));
  },
  computed: {
    getCalendar(){
      return this.buildCalendar();
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.year = this.date.getFullYear();
    this.currentPage = this.date.getMonth();
    this.nameOfOneMonth = this.namesOfMonths[this.currentPage];
  },
  methods: {
    prevPage(){
      if (this.currentPage === 0) {
        this.currentPage = 12;
        this.year--;
      }
      this.nameOfClass = 'prev';
      this.currentPage--;
      this.nameOfOneMonth = this.namesOfMonths[this.currentPage];
    },
    nextPage(){
      if (this.currentPage === 11) {
        this.currentPage = -1;
        this.year++;
      }
      this.nameOfClass = 'next';
      this.currentPage++;
      this.nameOfOneMonth = this.namesOfMonths[this.currentPage];
    },
    isAnotherMonth(weekIndex, dayNumber) {
      if(weekIndex === 0 && dayNumber > 15) {
        // первая неделе и номер дня > 15
        return true
      }
      if (weekIndex === 4 && dayNumber < 15) {
        // последняя неделя и номер дня < 15
        return true
      }
      if (weekIndex === 5 && dayNumber < 15) {
        // последняя неделя и номер дня < 15
        return true
      }
      // день принадлежит текущему месяцу
      return false
    },
    currentDayOnCalendar(dayNumber){
      if(this.currentPage === this.date.getMonth() && dayNumber === this.date.getDate() && this.year === this.date.getFullYear()){
        return true
      }
      return false
    },
    getYear(){
      this.year = this.date.getFullYear();
    },
    getLastDayOfMonth(month) { // нахождение числа последнего дня в месяце
      let dateDaysInMonth = new Date(this.year, month + 1, 0);
      return dateDaysInMonth.getDate();
    },
    getNumberOfFirstDayInMonth(month){ //нахождение номера первого дня в месяце
      let dateFirstDayInMonth = new Date(this.year, month, 1);
      return dateFirstDayInMonth.getDay();
    },
    buildCalendar(){
      let massOfMonth = [];
      for (let months = 0; months < 12; months++){
        massOfMonth.push(months);
        massOfMonth[months] = [];
        for ( let daysInMonth = 1; daysInMonth <= this.getLastDayOfMonth(months); daysInMonth++){
          massOfMonth[months].push(daysInMonth);
          massOfMonth[months][daysInMonth] = [];
          for(let m = 0; m <= 8; m++){
            let v = this.eventsData.events[m].starts_at;
            let d = new Date(v);
            if(daysInMonth === d.getDate()){
              massOfMonth[months][daysInMonth].push(this.eventsData.events[m].memo)
            }
          }
        }
        // Заполняем начало каждого месяца числами из прошлого месяца
        if(this.getNumberOfFirstDayInMonth(months) > 0){
          let t = this.getLastDayOfMonth(months-1) + 1;
          for(let b = 0; b <= this.getNumberOfFirstDayInMonth(months) - 2; b++){
            t--;
            massOfMonth[months].unshift(t)
          }
        }else if(this.getNumberOfFirstDayInMonth(months) === 0){
          let t = this.getLastDayOfMonth(months-1) + 1;
          for(let nulldays = 0; nulldays <= 5; nulldays++){
            t--;
            massOfMonth[months].unshift(t);
          }
        }
        //Заполняем конец каждого месяца числами из будущего месяца
        if((this.getNumberOfFirstDayInMonth(months) === 0 || 
          this.getNumberOfFirstDayInMonth(months) === 6) &&
          (this.getNumberOfFirstDayInMonth(months + 1) > 1 &&
          this.getNumberOfFirstDayInMonth(months + 1) < 3)){
          let t = 0;
          for(let q = this.getNumberOfFirstDayInMonth(months + 1); q <= 7; q++){
            t++;
            massOfMonth[months].push(t);
          }
        } else{
          let t = 0;
          for(let q = this.getNumberOfFirstDayInMonth(months + 1); q <= 14; q++){
            t++;
            massOfMonth[months].push(t);
          }
        }
      }
      // разбиение большого массива месяц на 
      // меньшие массивы которые имеют по 7 элементов
      var longArray = massOfMonth[this.currentPage];
      var size = 7;

      var newArray = new Array(Math.ceil(longArray.length / size)).fill("")
          .map(function() { 
            return this.splice(0, size) 
          }, longArray.slice());
       //--------------------------------------------------   
        return newArray; // вывод самого календаря
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a filter function to filter by relevant dates.

I just wrote the following script:

```
function filterEventsByCalenderDates(calenderDates) {
  const jsonData = {
    meta: {
      unremovable: [1],
      types: [
        [1, 'public_holiday'],
        [2, 'day_off'],
        [4, 'birthday'],
        [8, 'meeting'],
        [16, 'other'],
      ],
    },
    events: [
      {
        id: 211,
        starts_at: '2019-03-08',
        ends_at: '2019-03-08',
        memo: 'Международный женский день',
        type: 3,
      },
      {
        id: 212,
        starts_at: '2019-10-07',
        ends_at: '2019-10-07',
        memo: 'День учителя',
        type: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 213,
        starts_at: '2019-10-14',
        ends_at: '2019-10-14',
        memo: 'День защитника Украины',
        type: 3,
      },
      {
        id: 214,
        starts_at: '2019-10-18T14:00:00Z',
        ends_at: '2019-10-18T15:00:00Z',
        memo: 'Созвон с Киевом',
        type: 8,
      },
      {
        id: 215,
        starts_at: '2019-10-18T09:00:00Z',
        ends_at: '2019-10-18T13:15:00Z',
        memo: 'Велопрогулка',
        type: 16,
      },
      {
        id: 216,
        starts_at: '2019-10-22',
        ends_at: '2019-10-22',
        memo: 'Гуляем в парке',
        type: 16,
      },
      {
        id: 217,
        starts_at: '2019-10-28',
        ends_at: '2019-11-03',
        memo: 'Конференция',
        type: 18,
      },
      {
        id: 218,
        starts_at: '2019-11-03T21:43:00Z',
        ends_at: '2019-11-03T21:43:00Z',
        memo: 'Самолёт домой',
        type: 16,
      },
      {
        id: 219,
        starts_at: '2019-11-11',
        ends_at: '2019-11-11',
        memo: 'ДР',
        type: 4,
      },
    ],
  };

  const filteredEvents = jsonData.events.filter(event => {
    // separate date from time
    const date = event.starts_at.split('T')[0];
    // validate if the date is part of selected calenderDates
    return calenderDates.includes(date);
  });

  console.log('filteredEvents', filteredEvents);
}

filterEventsByCalenderDates(['2019-10-22', '2019-11-03']);
```